# Change gmail div content after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Gmail extension for chrome. 
Basically, I've created a function that manipulates the DOM on click of the labels on the left.

However, when I click on any label, the function runs before it loads the corresponding view.

Eg: If i click on 'Starred' from the 'Inbox' view, the function runs for the inbox view and then it loads the Starred view.

To correct this, I used this:

```
$(selector-of-label).click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        success: function-to-manipulate-dom()
    });
});
```

This didn't work so I tried this:

```
$(selector-of-view).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        success: function-to-manipulate-dom()
    });
});
```

However, this didn't work either. What would be the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake was that you were calling the function and passing parameter will not.

```
$(selector-of-label).click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       success: function-to-manipulate-dom
   });
});
```